# how to write a small benchmark of getbytes with jmh?

Tags: java, jmh

I am new to JMH and benchmarking. I have written a small test of public byte[]getBytes(String charsetName) method. However maven fails to build. Here is my code:

```
package org.openjdk.jmh.samples;
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)

public class Test
{   @GenerateMicroBenchmark
   public byte [] testgetbyte (String Str)
   {   

   byte[] bytes = Str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
   return bytes;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {      
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(Test.class.getSimpleName())
            .warmupIterations(5)
            .measurementIterations(5)
            .forks(1)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();

}

    }
```

When I run : mvn clean install. I get a Build failure error message.

Comment: What is the maven error that you get ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@GenerateMicroBenchmark` seems to indicate you are using a very old version of JMH, please update. With JMH 1.7, this sample:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class Test {
    @Benchmark
    public byte[] test(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    }
}
```

...says:

```
[ERROR] /home/shade/temp/stest/src/main/java/org/openjdk/Test.java:
[19,19] Method parameters should be @State classes.
```

Which says exactly that `String str` is unacceptable as `@Benchmark` argument. Think about it: what `String` should JMH call this method with? Who will generate it? What it will contain? These answers should be provided by user via `@State` classes, as described in [JMHSample_03_States](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7e1c1c40872d/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_03_States.java) and [JMHSample_04_DefaultState](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7e1c1c40872d/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_04_DefaultState.java).

Comment: If I want to generate that string using a method, which annotation will I need ?

Comment: Please look at the linked samples.